# I get errors on Inconsistent indentation, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, random

Something is wrong here and i don't know what, this should be very easy to make but
i have no idea what i'm doing wrong here.

```
class Start:
        def myfunc():

            first = ["Obama", "Trump", "Biden"]

            second = ["finding", "looking at", "searching for"]

            third = ["Monkey", "Bandits", "Police"]
            
            firstselect = randrange(4)

            secondselect = randrange(4)

            thirdselect = randrange(4)

            print(first[firstselect], second[secondselect], third[thirdselect])

            choice = input("Want to generate again? (Y/N)")

            if choice == "y":
                    myfunc()
            else:
                    exit()
```

the error i get:

Error: Inconsistent indentation detected!

1. Your indentation is outright incorrect (easy to fix), OR
2. Your indentation mixes tabs and spaces.

To fix case 2, change all tabs to spaces by using Edit->Select All followed by Format->Untabify Region and specify the number of columns used by each tab.

Comment: Please show the _full, exact_ error message and ensure you are showing us accurate code. The best way to share code here is to paste it into your question, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. As currently shown, `def myfunc():` needs to be indented.

Comment: it was pasted like that, and when i indent it i still get the error message.

Comment: There are no indentation errors in the code as shown. However, there are two problems. If you try to run Start.myfunc() and enter 'y' as input, you will get 'myfunc' is not defined. Furthermore, you look to be trying to do this recursively which is probably not what you really want